# How do unicode block characters affect accessiblity?

Tags: accessibility, typography, special-characters

I'm formatting an online poem that uses blackout text for erasures. My plan is to use an XML block character ( █ `&block;`) or `&#9608;`) to replace the appropriate characters. Does this have any specific impacts on accessiblity? I'm especially curious how screen readers will handle it. I found [this recent article](https://www.elevenways.be/en/articles/screenreaders-special-characters) but the block character is not addressed.

Comment: Is it an idea to use a black background on erased characters and make the characters also black with a strikethrough? This makes them invisible but screen readers still read them with notification of the strikethrough/deletion.

Comment: That was my initial solution, but the characters are still visible. In this case the poem is re-written and the block simply represents the removed characters.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, **it does affect accessibility**. Most screen readers can't read symbols, and those that can only read a limited set. In these screen readers, your specific case is usually covered and they will render it as **"block"** or **"solid block"**, but many screen readers will simply ignore it. For example, [JAWS](https://www.freedomscientific.com/products/software/jaws/)'s latest version can read it, but Mac VoiceOver can't. It also depends on the level of [*verbosity*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_reader#Verbosity) the user has selected in the settings, so depending on this is quite *iffy* and risky.

In general, if this is for decorative purposes, then it won't be a problem. Otherwise, if this is functional, I suggest you use an image with an `alt` description.

## Resources

- https://business.scope.org.uk/article/accessibility-screen-readers-special-characters-and-unicode-symbols
- https://www.pubcom.com/blog/2013_12-03/unicode-accessibility.html

Comment: Thank you. The blocks in this case function similar to ellipses–they represent a string of removed characters. In some cases that is a group of multiple blocks. Visually the blocks blend together and are easy to scan. If they are each individually announced it would be a poor experience.

Comment: well, but the thing is that you can't think of how they visually look, it's a completely different paradigm. Nevertheless, you can use conditionals, like `if block = 1 (use 'alt=deleted content'); else --> group blocks in one single element --> 'alt=N blocks deleted' `. Not sure which language are you using, but this kind of code is quite trivial in Javascript